# Inconveniente al realizar tratamiento de errores en VBA con el manejador

Tags: excel, vba

Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien, les escribe Hernán Martínez desde Colombia, quiero pedirles el favor con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta al momento de querer trabajar con el manejo de datos On Error GoTo 0, tengo el siguiente código:

```
Sub DividirporceroGoTo0()

Dim A, B As Double ' se debe de cambiar esto (Tipo de datos) para que no me genere error
Dim resultado As Double

On Error GoTo ManejoDeError1
   A = Range("A2").Value
   B = Range("B2").Value
   resultado = A / B
   Range("C2").Value = resultado
   On Error GoTo 0  ' cierra el ManejoDeError1

ManejoDeError1:
 MsgBox "Para que la aplicación no presente desbordamientos, " & _
         " por eso remplazar el 0 por 10" ' & _  es salto de línea
 Range("B2").Value = 10
 Resume 0
Exit Sub ' importante este Exit Sub para cerrar el ciclo
End Sub
```

El problema se presenta es cuando el Manejador de errores (ManejoDeError1) se activa incluso cuando el valor de la celda B2 es diferente de 0, desafortunadamente no he podido arreglar dicho inconveniente.

Muchas gracias por su colaboración!

Answer (score 2):

VBA siempre ejecuta el código línea por línea, desde `Sub` hasta `End Sub`. Es su comportamiento principal. Eso sí, para el *error handling* (tratamiento de errores) disponemos del `On Error...`

Fíjate en esta parte de código:

```
On Error GoTo ManejoDeError1
A = Range("A2").Value
B = Range("B2").Value
resultado = A / B
Range("C2").Value = resultado
On Error GoTo 0  ' cierra el ManejoDeError1
```

Básicamente le estás diciendo a VBA "oye, durante las próximas líneas, si detectas algún error, vete directamente a la sección ManejoDeError1". Esta orden se elimina cuando se lee `GoTo 0`, que reactiva el comportamiento por defecto (aviso en pantalla).

Pero es que después de tu código sigue habiendo código y no le has dicho a VBA que se salga ni nada, por lo tanto, sigue ejecutando todo. Tu sección `ManejoDeError` no es una sección independiente, sigue siendo código que VBA va a leer.

En este caso, para evitarlo, puedes usar `Exit Sub` para **forzar** la finalización de ejecución del procedimiento (finalizar el Sub).

De hecho, en tu código tienes:

```
Exit Sub ' importante este Exit Sub para cerrar el ciclo
End Sub
```

Esto está mal siempre en cualquier escenario de programación posible. Ambos comandos hacen lo mismo, finalizan código, así que no tiene ningún sentido que haya 2 seguidos como los tienes, bajo ninguna cirscunstancia.

Dicho todo esto, lo único que tienes que hacer es mover el `Exit Sub` y ponerlo antes de tu control de errores, estabas muy cerca de lo que querías. Prueba así:

```
Sub DividirporceroGoTo0()

Dim A As Double, B As Double ' se debe de cambiar esto (Tipo de datos) para que no me genere error
Dim resultado As Double

On Error GoTo ManejoDeError1
A = Range("A2").Value
B = Range("B2").Value
resultado = A / B
Range("C2").Value = resultado
On Error GoTo 0  ' cierra el ManejoDeError1

'si VBA llega aquí es que el código se ejecutó sin errores y queremos salir del Sub
Exit Sub ' importante este Exit Sub para cerrar el ciclo



ManejoDeError1:
MsgBox "Para que la aplicación no presente desbordamientos, " & _
         " por eso remplazar el 0 por 10" ' & _  es salto de línea
Range("B2").Value = 10
Resume 0

End Sub
```

Por cierto, en tu código tenías puesto `Dim A, B As Double`. Esto define B como Double pero A no tiene tipo así que se define como Variant. Procura explicitar siempre cuando declares variables como he hecho yo.